# How to open a link when user clicks on Firebase notification in a Flutter App?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am using Firebase in a Flutter app. To send notifications, I am using [Firebase Messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) plugin. Whenever I send a notification using Firebase website, the notification just opens the app when user clicks on it. I want to send a notification which opens a URL instead of the app.

I don't know if this information is useful: while composing a notification on Firestore, I always put `click_action` as `FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK` in "Custom data" section in Additional Options.

Comment: I think that you will still have to go through the intermediary step of opening the app, which then handles the message and launches a browser to the desired URL.

Comment: @samthecodingman ok, but how will the app know the user has clicked on the notification and which URL to open?

Comment: The same way you embeded the `FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK` in the custom data section. Just add in something similar to `{"action": "open-url", "url": "https://exampe.com"}` in that same spot

Comment: @samthecodingman like this: https://imgur.com/XYISEUq ?

Comment: Exactly. Then in each of your notification handlers, look for that property and act on it if present.

Answer (score 3):

You can use onLaunch() and onResume() methods to handle notification's opening action.

for more information of notification's reaction on different platforms please see below link:
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging#receiving-messages

```
 _firebaseMessaging.configure(
       onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
         print("onMessage: $message");
       },
       onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
       onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
         print("onLaunch: $message");
       },
       onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
         print("onResume: $message");
       },
     );
```

And you can use url_launcher to open URLs:
https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher